# Sync apps from specific device?

Tags: sync

My new phone got synced to my table instead of my old phone.  It didn't list my old phone as an option to sync from.

Is there a way to sync my installed apps and data from my old phone?
Getting the screen layouts synced would be nice too.

All the articles I can find are just "sync to Google", but not to sync to a particular device.

If it matters, the old phone still (mostly) works.

Comment: Do you use the same Google account on all devices (old phone, new phone and tablet)?

Comment: I have the same personal account everywhere, but some devices also have a business account.  Why would this matter?

Comment: It matters because backups are tied to a specific Google account. And you can only select one backup account at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you have Google backing up your data on the phone you want to sync from. On your old phone, navigate to **Settings > Backup & reset > (Google Backup)** and ensure that `Back up my data` is `On`. Also ensure that your `Backup account` is the account which you're logging into on your new phone.

After your old phone syncs (which may take some time, but it will let you know when), you should be able to see your phone on your new device as you are setting it up. *You may need to factory reset your new phone in order to see the list of Google backup devices.*

Comment: The old phone was backed up.  However, it wasn't shown in the list as I brought up the new phone.  I'm not about to reset the new phone and start over.

Comment: You should still confirm the settings on your old phone to make sure that it has the backup was set up properly. Also, there is currently no way to restore from a device backup without factory resetting your phone.